# jQuery slideToggle Not Closing Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is opening the divs fine, but when I click on the button again, instead of closing it's re-opening the divs. How can I close then on second click?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.showhide').click(function(e) {
    $(this).nextAll('.dropdown:lt(1)').slideToggle(100);
  });
  
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var container = $(".dropdown");
    if (container.is(':visible') && !$(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length) {
      container.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="showhide">Button</a><br />

<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Update</a>
  <a href="#">Delete</a>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Update</a>
  <a href="#">Delete</a>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Update</a>
  <a href="#">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It works just fine for me

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet where it seems to be working exactly as it should be. Could you edit your question to include more information about what the exact issue is

Comment: your snippet works fine.what is the issue?

Comment: @krishnar Sorry. Updated the Question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan My Fault. Updated the question :)

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Please check updated question!

Comment: @Randomix why you written mouseup event?

Comment: @krishnar In order to close the 'div' whenever user click somewhere else  on webpage :)

Comment: @Randomix when clicked outside you want to close all dropdown divs or just first one?

Comment: @krishnar Sir, At one click only one div should open or close & if user click outside it should close the div :)

Comment: @Randomix check my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Attach a click event to the window which closes the div. Attach a click event to the button which stops propagation to the document body***

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {

$('.showhide').click(function(e) {

$(this).nextAll('.dropdown:lt(1)').slideToggle(100);
e.stopPropagation();
});


$(window).click(function(e) {
  var container = $(".dropdown");
  if (container.is(':visible') && !$(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length) {
  container.hide();
  }
});



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" class="showhide">Button</a><br />

<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Update</a>
  <a href="#">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW, Working Perfectly fine. Thank You very much Sir :)

Comment: Sir, how can I prevent it from opening multiple divs at one time ?

Answer (score 1):

Test with

```
$(this).nextAll('.dropdown:lt(1)').is(":visible"))
```